# How to get all records from two tables with three joins in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have three tables (questions, answers, user) and I want to query all questions and answers posted by user.

Here is my code:

```
$query = $this->db->select('user.*,questions.*,answers.*')
    ->from('user')
    ->join('questions','questions.user_id = user.u_id','LEFT')
    ->join('answers','answers.user_id = user.u_id','LEFT')
    ->where('user.u_id',$profile[0]['u_id'])
    ->group_by('user.u_id')
    ->get();
echo $query->num_rows();
```

I have 1 posted question and 1 answer in my tables, but when I am trying this code it gives me only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with method..

write your query in single line like this
`$query= "select * from  user where" ;`  as well  ( this is only query example you have to write your query)

then

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query )) {
            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                print_r($res);
            }

            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
```

in this case  $connection is a your database connection

Comment: i am trying since 1 hrs but its not working could you solve this problem..?

Comment: did you try with my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried outer join, instead left join?
Maybe even a left outer join, solves your problem, just try it.

Oh, and instead of 'num_rows()' i suppose you just want to use 'row()' to
retrieve all table´s data.

```
$this->db->select('user.*,questions.*,answers.*');
$this->db->join('questions','questions.user_id = user.u_id','OUTER LEFT');
$this->db->join('answers','answers.user_id = user.u_id','OUTER LEFT');
$this->db->where('user.u_id',$profile[0]['u_id']);
$this->db->group_by('user.u_id')
$query = $this->db->get('user')->row();

echo $query;
```

I´ve changed a little your write, just copy and test it if you´d want